# HHVM 3.0.1 FastCGI keeps dying on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, fastcgi, hhvm

It seems the my HHVM FastCGI server keeps dying after about 10 requests. Brand new Ubuntu and HHVM install.

```
root@john:/# hhvm --version
HipHop VM 3.0.1 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.0.1-0-g97c0ac06000e060376fdac4a7970e954e77900d6
Repo schema: a1146d49c5ba0d6db903beb3a4ed8a3766fef182
```

And the server info:

```
root@john:/# uname -a
Linux john.authpilot.com 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 16:19:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@john:/# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
```

Just trying to run a poor little Laravel app. :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a memory issue like Daniel stated. HHVM needs more than 512MB to run, preferably much more.

Answer (score 3):

The JIT kicks in after about 10 requests, so you might have found a bug in the JIT.

Try installing a debug package (hhvm-dbg), run HHVM in gdb and then post the backtrace once it crashes.

Comment: When I try to debug it, this happens:
    root@john:~# gdb --args hhvm --mode server --config /etc/hhvm/server.ini -vPidFile=/var/run/hhvm/pid
    Reading symbols from /usr/bin/hhvm...Killed

It seems like it's using all of the available memory (this box has 450MB available).

Comment: @SmilingDevil Try increasing your system/VM memory first. The translation cache (where HHVM stores the x86 instructions) needs quite a bit of memory. If that works, you can try reducing JIT cache reserved memory size. This is how you can do that: https://gist.github.com/danslo/fcaa47b6ea8bf948b999 - notice those are bytes. So respectively 64MB, 64MB and 16MB. The size you need for the TC depends on the size of your program.

Comment: That seems to be it Daniel, I put it as an answer.